# Installing shopstory on contentful asks for access token and canvas url

Tags: contentful

I'm trying to install [shopstory](https://www.shopstory.app/) on contentful but I'm stuck at the step where I'm asked to provide a canvas URL and a shopstory access token.
I visited the website but could not find any hits as to how I would get those two details.
I wrote to the shopstory team some time ago but no responses so far.

Has anyone ever successfully installed this app on contentful?
If yes, how did you get these two details?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must contact the Shopstory team to get an access token. The Canvas URL is a link to the page where the canvas will be rendered.

Here is a [link](https://docs.shopstory.app/getting-started-next.js-+-contentful) to the documentation.